# Как установить константное поле в классе попозже? Как вызвать конструктор попозже?

Tags: c++

Есть класс с константным секретным полем. А этот секрет устанавливает удалённая функция. Как это константное значение установить попозже? Или может быть как-то чтобы конструктор позже вызвался?

```
class C {
public :
  C(std::string const & );
  ~C(void);
private :
  std::string const pass ;
} ;

void SetPassword(C&);

int main(){

  C c;
  // error: no matching function for call to ‘C::C()’

  SetPassword(c);
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что в таком случае проблема **в самом дизайне**.

Comment: Это старая проблема, в классах иногда нужно вызвать конструктор элемента чуток попозже. Пусть даже он не константный. @Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В С++17 можно аналогично использовать `std::optional<>`

```
class Alpha
{
    std::optional<const std::string> m_pwd;
public:
    void setPwd(const std::string& pwd)
    {
        if(m_pwd)
        {
             throw std::logic_error("pwd is already set");
        }
        m_pwd.emplace(pwd);
        //m_pwd=pwd - ошибка компиляции
    }
    void clPwd()
    {
        if(!m_pwd)
        {
             throw std::logic_error("pwd is not set");
        }
        m_pwd.reset();
    }
};
```

Comment: Если уж делать поле класса не константным, то можно было оставить просто `std::string pass;`

Comment: Тогда не будет разницы между "пароль не задан" и "пароль задан и пустой"

Comment: Так а вопрос был про "Есть класс с константным секретным полем." А тут его нет. Если поле можно менять, то и проблемы никакой нет.

Comment: Никто не видит константность ни в задаче ни в ответе. Куда все смотрят? @user7860670

Comment: Там есть константность - поле нельзя поменять простым присваиванием, компилятор гавкнет.

Comment: Получается `(bool)` - это мой `Addr()`. А `emplace` - это мой `Construct` ? Будем стремиться в будущее.

Comment: Есть еще одно отличие - Стандарт прямо запрещает авторам STL реализовывать optional<> с использованием кучи. Так что это еще и "бесплатно" по части выделения динамической памяти.

Comment: По поводу кучи не понял. Всё пашет молча. https://godbolt.org/z/z1xzffPn4

Comment: std::optional<T> не никогда не использует кучу для хранения внутри себя объекта T, не смотря на то, что позволяет его создавать и удалять динамически

Answer (score -2):

Можно создать объект в свободной памяти *(в куче)*. Но при этом нужно не забыть эту память освободить. А если нужно чтобы объект хранился в стеке, то поможет C++ структура **union**. Элементы в этой структуре инициализируются вручную и удаляются тоже. Чтобы не было проблем с забывчивостью поможет дополнительный класс **LazyC**, который будет это делать сам.

```
..
union {
  C res ;
} ;
bool  flagres { false } ;
```

Инициализировать класс будет сам этот дополнительный класс так :

```
..
if(not flagres) {
  new ( & res ) C { pas } ;
  flagres = true ; }
```

И удалять тоже сам :

```
..
if(flagres) {
  flagres = false ;
  res.~C(); }
```

---

Полный код :

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Winline -std=c++11 -Os lazyclass.cpp -o lazyclass
# include <string>
class C {
public :
  C(std::string const & );
  ~C(void);
  void Work(void);
private :
  std::string const pass ;
} ;

# include <iostream>

inline  C::C(std::string const & p):pass{p}{
  std::cout<<"C"<<std::endl;}
  
inline  C::~C(){
  std::cout<<"~C"<<std::endl;}

void C::Work(void) {
  std::cout<<"C:Work:pass="<<pass<<std::endl; }
  
class LazyC {
public :
  LazyC(void);
  ~LazyC(void);
  C * Addr ( void ) ;
  void Construct(std::string const & );
private :
  union {
    C res ;
  } ;
  bool  flagres { false } ;
} ;

LazyC::LazyC(void){
  std::cout<<"LazyC"<<std::endl;}

LazyC:: ~ LazyC(void){
  if(flagres) {
    flagres = false ;
    res.~C(); }
  std::cout<<"~LazyC"<<std::endl; }

C * LazyC::Addr(void) {
  if(flagres)
    return  & res ;
  return nullptr; }
  
void LazyC::Construct(std::string const & pas){
  if(not flagres) {
    new ( & res ) C { pas } ;
    flagres = true ; } }
  
void SetPassword(LazyC & );

int main() {
  LazyC args ;
  SetPassword(args);
  if(C * c = args.Addr()){
    C & cl = * c ;
    // работа с C
    cl.Work(); } }

void SetPassword(LazyC & lc) {
  lc.Construct( "secret" ) ; }
```

Результат :

```
$ ./lazyclass 
LazyC
C
C:Work:pass=secret
~C
~LazyC
```

Comment: как мне кажется, автор вопроса хотел константную переменную-член сделать. Тогда код ответа ни о чем.

Comment: @KoVadim ¿А вас не смущает, что автор вопроса и ответчик - один и тот же пользователь? Но ответ конечно мутный... Если можно было менять `SetPassword`, так и конструктор там же можно было вызвать и ничего дополнительно не городить...

Comment: о, вот это поворот.

Comment: Похоже на велосипед над std::optional<const std::string>

Comment: Насчёт семнадцатого стандарта я ещё не дошёл. Напишите сами другой ответ если не сложно. @gbg

Comment: Вот если-бы кто-нибудь нашёл это удобство в одиннадцатом стандарте было-бы замечательно. А-то минусы рисуют. За что?

Comment: В C++11 можно попытаться притянуть boost::optional

Comment: Когда только стали развиваться плюсы было **очень** много недоделок. Я резко ушёл в Си. По-этому вот такой Си подход к решению задачи сделал. Никто так и не сказал где у меня БАГ. Насчёт **boost** никогда не юзал, только стандарт, так-как чтобы скинуть `opensource` трудно объяснить, что только у меня будет компилироваться. @gbg

Comment: @AlexGlebe при всем уважении, это все было актуально как минимум лет 10 назад, а большинство глюков было связано к кривой поддержкой STL в C++ Builder

Comment: Вы слишком преувеличиваете давность. Ракеты управляются из доса и не плачут. Из свежей стабильной операционки `g++ (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0 Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` компилятор токо-токо дописал свежак. @gbg